# How to install Samsung Magician?

Tags: software-installation, ssd

How to install [Samsung Magician](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/downloads/software/Samsung_Magician_DC_Linux_64bit.zip)?

I downloaded the zip file for Linux 64bit but I can't install it.

Comment: The install guide indicates that it runs on Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, and 10.

Comment: What is displayed on the image? No one will open the link if you don't describe the content.

Comment: but have a linux 64 bit link

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). Why do you want to install that software? What are you actually trying to achieve? Most of its functions can be performed by native Linux tools.

Comment: my ssd not max performance

Comment: There is nothing to install. Just extract the binary and then `chmod +x` it. Then read http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/downloads/document/Samsung_Magician_DC_Brand_v2_User_Guide.pdf to see the command line options you can use.

Comment: @ÖmerGedik: How do you know? Did you run reliable tests? Even though the application is called “Magician” it cannot actually increase the performance *magically*. The only more or less special thing it can do is to update the firmware.

Answer (score 4):

No installation needed, just unzip and give it execution permission.

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) then `cd` to the zip file location. For example, if you saved the file in the `Downloads` directory:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   ```
2. Unzip the downloaded file. A file named `magician` will be extracted to the current directory.

   ```
   unzip Samsung_Magician_DC_Linux_64bit.zip
   ```
3. The extracted file must have execution privilege or it won't run:

   ```
   chmod +x magician
   ```
4. Now you can run it:

   ```
   sudo ./magician [operation]
   ```

   Note that you have to inform a path before the file name because usually the Download directory is not in the list of paths used to search for executable files. I prefer to put third party programs in `/usr/local/bin`:

   ```
   sudo mv magician /usr/local/bin
   ```

   Now you can run `magician` from anywhere in the directory tree without specifying a path:

   ```
   sudo magician [operation]
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   sudo magician --list
   ```